# How do I easily download Ubuntu ISOs via bittorrent from the command line?

Tags: downloads, iso, bittorrent

I want to download an Ubuntu ISO, preferably over bittorrent, and verify its integrity.

Currently, the following steps are required:

- start web browser, go to ubuntu.com, find download link
- find gpg signature for the checksums
- get the gpg key to check gpg signature of the checksums
- wait until download finished
- gpg verifiy
- checksum verification

Isn't there a simpler way? Just like

- apt-get install 12.04-64bit-ubuntu-iso
- apt-get install 12.04-32bit-server-iso
- etc.?

Of course, apt-get (or whatever it would be called) should **download over bittorrent** to remove load from the servers.

If it doesn't exist, it should probable post that at ubuntu brainstorm? Is there already such a tool? I wanted to ask before posting to brainstorm.

Comment: entirely possible with a bash script -- will need a command line torrent program to control -- sure it could be whipped up without to much trouble even for someone not familiar with bash scripting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *aria2c* and metalinks let you do a one-step, verified ISO download using the bittorrent protocol

It is extremely easy to do what you want using the `aria2` CLI download manager and the ISO [metalinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalink) available on the official download page, namely:

- Download an Ubuntu ISO
- Preferably over Bittorrent
- Automatically verify integrity of downloaded ISO

### Steps:

1. Install *aria2* with `sudo apt-get install aria2c`

   [image: Install via the software center]
2. Open the official download page for the release you want, e.g. for [Precise](http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/)

   ```
   http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise
   ```
3. Find the **metalink** for your ISO, e.g. `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.metalink`, and right-click to copy it to the clipboard
4. In the terminal, type and paste the link as `aria2c <URL of metalink>`

   - You can add the `--seed-time=0` option if you want *aria2c* to exit after downloading and not seed the ISO, e.g.

     ```
     aria2c --seed-time=0 http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/ubuntu-12.04-server-i386.metalink
     ```
5. Unless BitTorrent (**BT**) is not possible on your network, *aria2* will download the file as a torrent.
6. The BitTorrent protocol provides **automatic** built-in checksumming, and *aria2* will continually verify pieces as they are downloaded.

   - In short, if you download an official metalink over BT, a successful download means that you have the original, unmodified, complete file.

> ***Trick:*** You can remove the web browser, copy-paste etc. by simply typing the direct URL for *aria2* as `http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases` followed by this format:
>
> ```
> /release-name/ubuntu-release.version-variant-architecture.iso
> ```

#### Exception/manual verification:

If *aria2* had to download the ISO via HTTP/FTP (BT not available), or if you just want the security of double-verification, a one-liner in the following format should do it (split lines for readability)

```
wget -q -O- http://releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/MD5SUMS \
  | grep desktop-i386 | md5sum -c
```

- Success will show you, e.g. `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso: OK`
- `desktop-i386` should be replaced with the appropriate *version-architecture* you chose to download, e.g. *server-amd64*, *alternate-i386* etc.
- `MD5SUMS` can be replaced with `SHA1SUMS` or `SHA256SUMS`, with the corresponding `md5sum` at the end replaced with `sha1sum` or `sha256sum`
- *precise* in the URL can of course be replaced with whatever release you're downloading.